# Get getAttribute from button and toggle class name to body react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i want to improve my code, with several buttons that has custom class names (attr), when clicked should add to body tag (toggle), now is adding the first button only because for `("button")[0]` but should work for each button

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

function Test() {
  const [isClass, setIsClass] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const x = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].getAttribute("custom-class")
    document.body.classList.toggle(x, isClass)
  }, [isClass])

  return (
    <>
      <button custom-class='test1' onClick={() => setIsClass(!isClass)}>
        Setting test1 className
      </button>
       
      <button custom-class='test2' onClick={() => setIsClass(!isClass)}>
        Setting test2 className
      </button>
    </>
  )
}

export default Test
```

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to add class name to the body tag? what is the goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, @Naim Mustafa, Thanks for reply. for  css basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code.

```
let oldStyle = "";

const handleClick = (index) => {
  const x = [...document.getElementsByTagName("button")].map(value => value.getAttribute("custom-class"));
  document.body.classList.contains(x[index]) ? document.body.classList.remove(x[index]) : document.body.classList.add(x[index]);
  if(document.body.classList.length > 1) document.body.classList.replace(oldStyle, x[index]);
  oldStyle = x[index];
}

return (
  <>
    <button custom-class='test1' onClick={() => handleClick(0)}>
      Setting test1 className
    </button>
    
    <button custom-class='test2' onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>
      Setting test2 className
    </button>
  </>
)
```

Comment: Thank for reply,  is adding  two classes,  `<body class="test1 test2"></body>`  should be added one only

Comment: Hi @Kirill Savik,  almost close, the first click, the class appears, when it is clicked again, it should disappear, now it remains, it only disappears when another button is clicked, when the same button is clicked it should do Toggle

Comment: Thanks @Kirill Savik   +1

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to use DOM querying and manipulation directly with elements that are created and controlled by react. In your particular example it is ok to use `document.body`, but not ok to search for buttons, especially when you try to find them by tag name. To actually toggle a class in classList you don't need second parameter in most cases, so additional state is also not needed.

React way to get reference to element renderend by React would be to use [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper). However, in your particular case side effect can be launched inside event handler, so you don't need `useEffect` or `useRef`.

Your `onClick` handler can accept `event` object that is [Synthetic Event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html). It holds property [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) that holds reference to your button.

So, the easiest way would be simply to write like this:

```js
function Test() {
  function clickHandler(event) {
    let classToToggle = event.target.getAttribute("custom-class");
    document.body.classList.toggle(classToToggle);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button key="test1" custom-class="test1" onClick={clickHandler}>
        Setting test1 className
      </button>

      <button key="test2" custom-class="test2" onClick={clickHandler}>
        Setting test2 className
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

If you need to have only single className from the list, you can decide which class to enable or disable with a bit of a state. Since anything can add classes on body it might be useful to operate only on some set of classes and not remove everything.

Also, not mentioned before, but consider using `data` attribute as its purpose is to keep some additional data.

```js
function Test() {
  // this can come from props or be hardcoded depending on your requirements
  // If you intend to change it in runtime, consider adding side effect to cleanup previous classes on body
  let [classesList] = React.useState(["test1", "test2"]);
  let [activeClass, setActiveClass] = React.useState("");

  // You can switch actual classes in effect, if you want to
  function clickHandler(event) {
    let classToToggle = event.target.dataset.customClass;
    // we remove all classes from body that are in our list
    document.body.classList.remove(...classesList);
    if (activeClass === classToToggle) {
      setActiveClass("");
    } else {
      // if class not active - set new one
      document.body.classList.add(classToToggle);
      setActiveClass(classToToggle);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      {classesList.map((cn) => (
        <button key="cn" data-custom-class={cn} onClick={clickHandler}>
          Setting {cn} className
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Hedgehog, works fine, but when clicked both buttons is adding two classes, its possible to remove the previous class name

Comment: Oh, I thought that is what you want. To toggle different classNames you have plenty of options and viable option depends on your particular application. Thing is, everything on page can add classes to body, so if you only need to manipulate particular set and not interfere with what you had previously, consider this logic. If current class already active, toggle if off. If current class is not active - remove all classes from body that are in your list and add new active class. This can be done both - with effect and without - choose what better suits your final code. I'll edit my answer soon.